# Regex Patterns in Java

Tags: java, regex, posix, regex-negation

I am using Regex Patterns and I need to check that the beginning of the String is an HTML Simple Text and return that String.  So for example:

```
Hello World!<TAG> &nsbp;
```

Should return:

`Hello World!`

Comment: If you are parsing HTML you should use an HTML parser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege

Comment: "split" takes a regex as the first argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that if you're parsing large sections of text or entire files, you should force the String into a new reference otherwise you may get a memory leak due to substrings.

```
new String("Hello World!<TAG> &nsbp;".split("<")[0])
```

Comment: THanks for the response but I need to use Regex expressions

Comment: if you check the API for String.split, technically it is a regex :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"Hello World!<TAG> &nsbp;".split("<")[0]
```

should return `Hello World!`.